# Map two functions together in Functional Programming paradigm

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am learning Functional Programming in Python. I read that functions ideally do one thing, so how would I do big calculations if I can't pass in many functions at once

```
import datetime

birthdays = [
    datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 29),
    datetime.datetime(2006, 8, 9),
    datetime.datetime(1978, 5, 16),
    datetime.datetime(1981, 8, 15),
    datetime.datetime(2001, 7, 4),
    datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 30)
]

today = datetime.datetime.today()

def is_over_13(dt):
  delta = today - dt
  return delta.days >= 4745

def date_string(dt):
  return dt.strftime("%B %d")

def reverse(iterable):
  return iterable[::-1]

birth_dates = list(map(date_string, filter(is_over_13, birthdays)))
```

The code displays birthdays in a `date_string` filtered by those who are over 13.  I want to add the `reverse` function on top of the existing `map`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can (I am using your `reverse` function):

```
birth_dates = reverse(list(map(date_string, filter(is_over_13, birthdays))))
```

Or, you could just reverse the `birthdays` initially:

```
birth_dates = list(map(date_string, filter(is_over_13, reverse(birthdays))))
```

You could also use `reversed` instead of writing your own function.

Answer (score 2):

There's a built-in `reversed()` function that you could use. It returns an iterator, so you may want to wrap it with `list()`.

```
 birth_dates = list(reversed(map(date_string, filter(is_over_13, birthdays))))
```